# Instagram API Register New Client Not Showing Captcha

Tags: api, firefox, instagram, captcha, instagram-api

So I'm trying to register a new client on the instagram API. I have a business account and have done the proper steps prior to this. Everytime I fill out the "Register New Client ID" form and submit it, I get an error "The captcha solution was not correct. Please try again." But no there is no captcha for me to fill out!! Looking at the console errors it says the CSP page setting's are blocking this source https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js. I'm gonna take a wild guess and say that has the captcha I need that's not appearing..lol.

Anyway, I've disabled all my content blocking settings and JS is enabled on firefox (oh I'm using firefox developer edition btw) and no change. I've also tried this in chrome and safari, no change. I don't have this issue with other sites that use captchas.

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

'preciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue here on Google Chrome. Used IE11 (version 11.345.17134.0 to be exact), and captcha displayed instantly. I've successfully registered a new client

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to wait until Instagram team realizes to upgrade their *whatever* scripts & parameters.

I found myself in the same scenario:

1. I'm logged on Instagram
2. I land to instagram.com/developer/clients/register/ over Google Chrome 70.0.3538.102 (no extensions)
3. No captcha. And I get the following from the console:

[image: Google Chrome 70.0.3538.102 and devTools showing javascript issues over Instagram's dev client ID registration page]

*ps: I tried figuring out how to submit this specific report, but after several searches I find myself loosing too much time... to make them aware.*